# Django Pagination with get_absolute_url method

Tags: python, django, pagination

Are their any special rules with using Django's Paginator with the model method `get_absolute_url`?  I am trying to call this method, but it isn't working??

Here's my template:

```
<ul class="products thumb-info-list">
{% for product in products.object_list %}

    <li class="col-md-3 product">
        {% if product.on_sale %} 
        <a href="{{ product.get_ablsolute_url }}">
            <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>
        </a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="thumb-info">
            <a href="{{ product.get_ablsolute_url }}" class="add-to-cart-product">
                <span><i class="icon icon-tag"></i>{{ product.title }}</span>
            </a>
            <a href="{{ product.get_ablsolute_url }}">
                <span class="thumb-info-image">
                    <span class="thumb-info-act">
                        <span class="thumb-info-act-left"><em>View</em></span>
                        <span class="thumb-info-act-right"><em><i class="icon icon-plus"></i> Details</em></span>
                    </span>
                    <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ product.image_one }}">
                </span>
            </a>
            <span class="thumb-info-content">
                <a href="{{ product.get_ablsolute_url }}">
                    <h4>{{ product.title }}</h4>
                    <span class="price">
                        {% if product.on_sale %}
                        <del><span class="amount">${{ product.unit_price|floatformat:0 }}</span></del>
                        {% endif %}
                        <ins><span class="amount">${{ product.sale_price|floatformat:0 }}</span></ins>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a typo in your template:

```
product.get_ablsolute_url
```

should be:

```
product.get_absolute_url
```

Comment: Wowzers! Yea, I thot that it might be something like that. just need a fresh set of eyes on it. thanks!